# Oracle Materialized View Content-Based Refresh

Tags: oracle, refresh, materialized-views

How can I update each row with a specific value in a column from a Materialized View?

Example:

```
ID|VALUE|CLIENT
----------------
1 |A    |00
2 |B    |01
3 |C    |00
```

After an update the table looks like:

```
ID|VALUE|CLIENT
----------------
1 |B    |00
2 |D    |01
3 |C    |00
```

but the refresh shall only effect the rows of a the specific Client '00', so the MView shall look like:

```
ID|VALUE|CLIENT
----------------
1 |B    |00
2 |B    |01
3 |C    |00
```

is there any way to get that without replacing the MView with a table?

Answer (score 0):

I never tried it & can't right now as I have 11g XE available which doesn't support *it*, but you might: the keyword is *`partitioning`* (make sure your Oracle license is OK with it, as partitioning works in Enterprise Edition).

The idea is: create partition on CLIENT so that you could refresh only the '00' one.

Have a look at [Partitioning and Materialized Views](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/advmv.htm#i1006635) (this is the 11g documentation; if you use some other, find the appropriate documentation yourself).